# Amdatu OSGI Event Handler time delay to listen when other listener are listening

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, amdatu

I am using amdatu and using the osgi event listener for multiple bundle the issue is when i create more thread the event handler is working but its giving the response with time delay

Example : I have 2 event listener one will do the VM creation JOB in cloud Another event is just a ping pong call to check system up status

The Issue is when the first event listener is called and the VM job are processing and in the middle when i call the ping pong , the event is published but the listener is listening with more time delay, Is there any config to process all event in parallel?

Java Heap Memory Usage
Total Memory: 1364
Free Memory: 691
Used Memory: 672
Max Memory: 1820

So any know about this issue , say a fix

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do this on the EventAdmin side (I guess you are using EventAdmin). You should be able to spawn an ExecutorService on the EventListener side. So the listener is not blocked for longer periods.